# How to re-render Reactjs component after update in data?

Tags: reactjs

This is the structure of my component:

```
module.exports =  React.createClass({

    getInitialState(){
        data = .... //by connecting to a db server

        var properties = fun(...)   //other functions manipulating the data

        return {

            data:data,
            .... //other UI functions

        }

    onSearch(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var startdate = React.findDOMNode(this.ref.start).value;

            //******** here I want to update the data in the view using this new startdate  
            //so essentially I just want to replace "data = " in the getInitialState() bcoz I
            //want other data manipulation functions from getInitialState to run as well.       
        }

    render(){

        return(
            <form className = "dateform" onSubmit = {this.onSearch}>
                <input type = "text" ref = "start" />
            </form>

            ...

            //other UI return stuff
        )
    }
)}
```

How should I go about doing this //*******?

I want to update only the data variable in the getInitialState() based on what date I get in my form field. And later refresh the view with the new data. What changes should I make in the onSearch function?

Is this a correct way to do it?

```
onSearch()
{
     data = //make $.ajax call to get new data
    this.setState({
        data: data
   });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change component state on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183304/change-component-state-on-button-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the state [in documentation here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#how-state-works). You can change it by call setState method like this:

```
onSearch (e) {
    // get somehow new data

    this.setState({
        data: newData
    });
}
```