# Change component state on button click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The following is the HTML.

```
<script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/t39.3284-6/12624079_897774290317920_1379776191_n.js"></script>
<script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t39.3284-6/12624052_751451571621845_431133942_n.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="container">
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="" id="controls-size">Size : 
        <button id="controls-size-small">SMALL</button>
        <button id="controls-size-med">MEDIUM</button>
        <button id="controls-size-large">LARGE</button>
    </span>

  </div>
  <div id="game-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is the Javscript

```
var SizeEnum = {
  SMALL: 1,
  MEDIUM: 2,
  LARGE: 3
};

var Board = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          size: SizeEnum.MEDIUM
        };
      },

      componentWillMount: function() {
        if (this.state.size == SizeEnum.SMALL) {
          this.style = {
            width: 600 + 'px',
            height: 320 + 'px',
            margin: 'auto',
            border: '2px solid red'
          }
        } else if (this.state.size == SizeEnum.MEDIUM) {
          this.style = {
            width: 700 + 'px',
            height: 500 + 'px',
            margin: 'auto',
            border: '2px solid red'
          }
        } else if (this.state.size == SizeEnum.LARGE) {
          this.style = {
            width: 900 + 'px',
            height: 720 + 'px',
            margin: 'auto',
            border: '2px solid red'
          }
        }
      },

      render: function() {
          return ( < div style = {
            this.style
          } > < /div>
    )
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<Board / > , document.getElementById("game-container"));
```

And some CSS

```
#game-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 32px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I want is that when the appropriate button is clicked, the Board component be resized to the appropriate size.

I've tried doing it like this

```
var board = ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("game-container"));

document.getElementById("controls-size-small").onclick = changeBoardSize;
document.getElementById("controls-size-med").onclick = changeBoardSize;
document.getElementById("controls-size-large").onclick = changeBoardSize;

function changeBoardSize(event) {
    var etid = event.target.id;
    console.log(etid);
    if (etid == "controls-size-small") {
        // method 1
        board.state.size = SizeEnum.SMALL;
    } else if (etid == "controls-size-med") {
        // method 2
        board.state.size = SizeEnum.MEDIUM;
        ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("game-container"));
    } else if (etid == "controls-size-small") {
        // method 3
        board.setState({size: SizeEnum.SMALL});
        ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("game-container"));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have html with buttons in it? React is component based and all "html" should be in JSX within a render function

Comment: agree with the above, those buttons should be components, then this is pretty simple

Comment: Ok so I make the buttons components.. then?

Comment: @dorado after making buttons the components, you should be able to attach an onClick function to them which in that onClick can change the state

Comment: so that onClick on the button will be able to change the sate of the board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the state of a React component like that. And the component should be responsible for setting its own state.

Inside your Board component, set up event listeners in componentDidMount. The best solution would be to let the buttons be part of the React application, but that's beyond the scope of this question. So let's say that the buttons are not part of the React application, then do something like this:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  ...
  ...
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var that = this;
    document.getElementById("controls-size-small").addEventListener('click', that.changeBoardSize, false);
    document.getElementById("controls-size-med").addEventListener('click', that.changeBoardSize, false);
    document.getElementById("controls-size-large").addEventListener('click', that.changeBoardSize, false);
  }

  changeBoardSize: function(e){
    /* get the element id and do the enum things here */
    this.setState({
      size: newSize
    });
  }
  render: function(){
    ...
    ...
  }
});
```

Then just move all that componentWillMount style stuff to the `render` function.

*Update*

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/r525ux66/

Comment: The buttons are critical to the scope of this question. Rendering UI elements in such a way that they can interact with the React state is fundamental to understanding and using React.

Comment: Absolutely, and in most common scenarios, I will agree. But in the real world, with project managers and different pieces of code that is beyond your control playing together, there will be exceptions to the rule. And since OP presented the problem with the buttons outside the application, well, here's one possible solution.

Comment: @dannyjolie This seems a lucrative option but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ah gotcha. I'm still learning and just learned how to get at the state from outside the component. I guess I'm blessed that my project is green fields React, so everything can be in React.

Comment: @dorado Then you are doing something wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/r525ux66/

Comment: @dannyjolie - Thank you for helping. Sure are on a reactjs streak. :D

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the wrong approach. The hardest part about react is "Thinking in React." If you want things to work properly, the notion of reaching into the DOM directly, like you are doing with document.getElementById, is off the table.

The simplest way for you to get started is to render your button inside the render function of your Board component. Then you can put a click handler inside the Board component to set the state.

This should get you started:

```
    handleClick: function (event) {
       this.setState({ size: SizeEnum.SMALL });
    },
    render: function() {
              return ( 
                  <div>
                      <div style = { this.style}></div>
                      <input type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}
                  </div>
              )
    }
```

Once you get this working, if you want to separate your button from your button, then you will want to look into using a Flux implementation to pass state from component to component.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change state of React component directly. Use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) function instead. When you call [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) React will re-render compoment.

Add new function setSize to your Board compoment:

```
    var Board = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            size: SizeEnum.MEDIUM
         };
     },
     setSize: function(size) {
        this._setStyle(size);
        this.setState({size: size});
     },
     _setStyle: fiunction(size) {
        if (size == SizeEnum.SMALL) {
             this.style = {
               width: 600 + 'px',
               height: 320 + 'px',
               margin: 'auto',
               border: '2px solid red'
            }
        } else if (size == SizeEnum.MEDIUM) {
            this.style = {
              width: 700 + 'px',
              height: 500 + 'px',
              margin: 'auto',
              border: '2px solid red'
           }
        } else if (this.state.size == SizeEnum.LARGE) {
            this.style = {
              width: 900 + 'px',
              height: 720 + 'px',
              margin: 'auto',
              border: '2px solid red'
           }
       }
     },
     componentWillMount: function() {
        this._setStyle(this.state.size);
     },
     // ................
     render: function() {
      return ( <div style={this.style}></div>)
     }
     });

     function changeBoardSize(event) {
         var etid = event.target.id;
         console.log(etid);
        if (etid == "controls-size-small") {
            board.setSize(SizeEnum.SMALL);
        } else if (etid == "controls-size-med") {
             board.setSize(SizeEnum.MEDIUM);
        } else if (etid == "controls-size-small") {
             board.setSize(SizeEnum.LARGE);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an anti pattern though this is the right way to achieve what you are looking for.

Since ReactDOM.render returns an instance of the component that is rendered, you can use that and update it's state.

```
    function changeBoardSize(event) {
        var etid = event.target.id;
        console.log(etid);
        if (etid == "controls-size-small") {      
            board.setState({size: SizeEnum.SMALL});
        } else if (etid == "controls-size-med") {
            board.setState({size: SizeEnum.MEDIUM});     
        } else if (etid == "controls-size-small") {
            board.setState({size: SizeEnum.LARGE});
        }
    }
```

The right way to do this, is to make buttons components of Board and attach event handlers on them eg :

```
var Board = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          size: SizeEnum.MEDIUM
        };
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
           <a href="#" onClick={this.onSizeChangeClick.bind(this, SizeEnum.SMALL)}>Small</a>
           <a href="#" onClick={this.onSizeChangeClick.bind(this, SizeEnum.MEDIUM)}>Medium</a>
           <a href="#" onClick={this.onSizeChangeClick.bind(this, SizeEnum.LARGE)}>Large</a>
        </div>  
        )
      },

      onSizeChangeClick: function(size, event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          size: size
        });
      }
})
```

Comment: As you can see, I've already tried this in method 3 above but it doesn't work.

Comment: @dorado What method have you tried, can you send me a plunker ?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that the result of ReactDom.render will allow you to setState on that component. Learned something new! Anyways, I still stand by my answer that it's more Reactified to keep everything in React.

Comment: Binding inside the render method will cause multiple copies of onSizeChangeClick to be created, which may cause issues in high volumes of events. It's better to do the bind command in the constructor.

Comment: @DataMania I totally agree